# Mock ionic-native for testing

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm writing an ionic 2 app I'd like to test. Therefore, I need the ability to mock ionic native plugins, i.e. I want to test how the application reacts to network changes. I tried out to import the modules and override its properties:

```js
import {Network, Connection} from 'ionic-native';
Network.connection = Connection.WIFI;
```

but this does not work (`'Cannot set property connection of function Network() { } which has only a getter'`). Is there any possibility to mock this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matter is being discussed [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/165), and probably those classes with static methods will be replaced by injectable services.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done, and don't know if it's a good approach, is to set an property of the component with the instance of the Ionic Native's object and when I test, override this property with a mock. Example with AppVersion:

component.ts

```
import { AppVersion } from 'ionic-native';
export class YourComponent {
  public appVersion: any = AppVersion;
  //etc
}
```

in the component.spec.ts

```
import { AppVersionMock } from '../../mocks';
describe('YourComponent', () => {
  //creates fixtures, get instance, etc...

  //in some assertion
  it('should have new version number', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.componentInstance.appVersion = new AppVersionMock()
  })
})
```

and mocks.ts have something like

```
export class AppVersionMock {
  version = 20;
  public getVersionNumber() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.version)
    });
  }
}
```